# Cool APIs to help learn C++?

Tags: c++, api, computer-science

This isnt quite a programming question, but for my CS class next semester, we're learning C++. Now I'm gonna be proactive and learn some over hte break, and I was wondering if there were any cool API's that are in C++ out there that are fun and not crazy hard, that I could tinker with to help solidify what im learning. Any Ideas?

(since this is a really broad question figured these might help narrow it down):

I run OSX and Ubuntu Linux
I have a kinect i want to tinker with at some point
I'd like to learn how to do network programing
I want to learn how to do hacker type things (in a legal way preferably)

Comment: "Not a real question". Since this is for school/personal, I'd pick something **fun** that you **want to learn** and **play** with. (I do not know what **interests you**, so I cannot say more.)

Comment: Define "cool", "fun", and "crazy hard".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend any API.

What I would recommend when learning any programming language is writing code.  If you don't have any idea of your own, then I highly recommend solving computer science problems.

[SPOJ](http://www.spoj.pl/)  has a database of problems, everything from easy problems to really challenging ones.  This will improve not only your programming skills, but you will also learn a lot about data structures and algorithms.  A cool thing about it is that you submit your solution and the online judge will let you know if your solution is correct.

[UVa Online Judge](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8)  is another great site.

Comment: Agreed. APIs only distract you from learning core concepts. I tried learning MFC as my first C++ exercise, and I came away with some gross misconceptions about the language.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the Boost C++ APIs. They have a lot of neat APIs for all sorts of applications. Some of them could qualify as "crazy hard" though.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/). It is a nice graphical toolkit library in C++, and it is free software so you can (and should) look into its source code.